# Plot multivariable function with constraints

Tags: functions

Is it possible to plot some function similar to $f(x,y)=x+2y$ with a  constraint like this? $x2+y2=5$

We want to optimize (i.e. find the minimum and maximum value of) a function, $f(x, y)$, subject to the constraint $g(x,y)=0$. And I would like to know if it is possible to plot function f with the restriction g

Thanks

Comment: This question does not make sense to me. What do you mean "print" a function ? Do you mean define and plot ?

Comment: Use `ContourPlot`, but fix your variable names first.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: The problem is this: We want to optimize (i.e. find the minimum and maximum value of) a function, f(x, y), subject to the constraint g(x,y)=0.

And I would like to know if it is possible to plot function f with the restriction g

Comment: Do you mean `x^2 + y^2 == 5`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like?

```
Plot3D[x + 2 y, {x, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]}, {y, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]},  
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 < 5]]
```

Comment: Plot3D[4000*x*y^3, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x + 2/3*y - 1.3 = 0]] works in the same way for me with or without constraint

Comment: Try use less/greater in  Function[{x, y}, x + 2/3*y - 1.3 <> 0.

Comment: that is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

**Using `ConditionalExpression`:**

```
Plot3D[ConditionalExpression[x + 2 y, x^2 + y^2 <= 5],
 {x, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]}, {y, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Add the option `PlotStyle->None` to display only the boundary:

[image]

**Using `MeshFunctions`:**

```
Plot3D[x + 2 y, {x, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]}, {y, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2], Mesh -> {{5}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], 
 MeshShading -> {Automatic, None}, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Use `MeshShading -> {None, None}` to get the boundary only:

[image]

Comment: that is what I was looking for :)