# RegionFunction with equalities?

Tags: plotting, constraint

Can we use RegionFunction with Plot3D for equalities? This answer ([Plot multivariable function with constraints](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157490/plot-multivariable-function-with-constraints)) has shown the use of RegionFunction with inequalities, but the same commands don't work for equality constraints. Any way out?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are trying to achieve, with the code you currently have? Did you see the use of `PlotStyle -> None` in the linked question's answers to obtain only the boundary of the region identified with the inequality? That would be functionally equivalent to plotting the equality.

Comment: @MarcoB, the options given in the other answer in that link are not applicable in this case. I used Plot3D[x + 2 y, {x, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]}, {y, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]},  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 - 1]] and it gives a circular 'hole' in the plot of x+2y, instead of showing just the circle on top of the plot of x+2y

Answer (score 2):

This approach may not be the most direct, but here is how I envisioned using the techniques shown in [kglr's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157500/27951) to the linked question ([Q157490](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/157490/27951)) to achieve your goal, as I understand it:

```
Show[
  (* This generates the plot of the surface of interest *)
  Plot3D[x + 2 y, {x, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]}, {y, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]}],

  (* This generates the region boundary *)
  Plot3D[
    x + 2 y, {x, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]}, {y, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]},
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 < 1],
    BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black],
    PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> None
  ]
]
```

[image: 3D plot with boundary]